# How can I implement a generic interface in Rhino JS?

Tags: java, oop, generics, interface, rhino

I have an application that contains a generic interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface<T> {
    public int calcStuff(T input); 
}
```

I can clearly implement this in Java:

```
public class Implementor implements IMyInterface<FooObject>{
    public int calcStuff(FooObject input){ ... }
}
```

I have found a tutorial on implementing Java non-generic interfaces in Rhino and can verify that it works in my context.

As far as I understand Javascript has no generics due to the dynamic type system and other factors, so Rhino does not provide such a concession in its JS parser. Any attempts to do research lead me to a plethora of results about Rhino *mocks* generic interfaces but not Rhino JS generic interface implementation.

Comment: could you clarify in what sense it is not working? Does rhino complain when you provide an implementation? As i understand it, any interface in JS is generic (or typed to `Object`) so I wonder what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @oberhamsi It is not working as I cannot find a reference of any sort to a syntax to refer to a generic class in Rhino JavaScript. Would that imply that creating an interface with `calcStuff(FooObject obj)` implicitly return a `IMyInterface<FooObject>` implementation?

Comment: No matter how `calcStuff()` looks like, it will behave like `IMyInterface<Object>`. I don't know if that's what actually happens behind the scenes but if I implement java.util.Map in rhino it accepts anything, i.e. acts like `java.util.Map<Object, Object>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a Javascript point of few, there are no generics, no interfaces, not even classes. In Javascript you have [Objects with functions that may be created from prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

To "implement" a Java interface in Javascript only means, to provide some Javascript object, that has the same function names as the interfaces method names, and these functions have the same number of arguments as the corresponding interface methods.

So to implement the generic example interface you provided, you can write something like this:

```
myGenericInterfaceImpl = new Object();
// Generic type is supposed to be <String> int calcStuff(String)
myGenericInterfaceImpl.calcStuff = function(input) { 
        println("--- calcStuff called ---");
        println("input" + input);
        println("typeof(input):" + typeof(input));

        // do something with the String input
        println(input.charAt(0));
        return input.length();
    }
```

Here it is assumed, that the intended generic class is of type `String`.

Now lets say, you have a Java class, that accepts this interface with a generic `String` type:

```
public static class MyClass {
    public static void callMyInterface(IMyInterface<String> myInterface){
        System.out.println(myInterface.calcStuff("some Input"));
    }
}
```

You can then call this method from Javascript like so:

```
// do some Java thing with the generic String type interface
Packages.myPackage.MyClass.callMyInterface(new Packages.myPackage.IMyInterface(myInterfaceImpl)));
```

#### Some background information on the topic

If you are interested in what goes on behind the scenes in Rhino, when implementing a Java interface in Javascript, I recommend to have a look at the following Rhino classes:

- https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/jdk13/VMBridge_jdk13.java
- https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/src/org/mozilla/javascript/InterfaceAdapter.java

Essentially the static method `InterfaceAdapter#create()` will call `VMBridge#newInterfaceProxy()`, which returns a Java `Proxy` for the interface, that uses an instance of `InterfaceAdapter` to handle method invocations on your interface. This proxy will map any Java method call on the interface to the corresponding Javascript functions.

```
 **
 * Make glue object implementing interface cl that will
 * call the supplied JS function when called.
 * Only interfaces were all methods have the same signature is supported.
 *
 * @return The glue object or null if <tt>cl</tt> is not interface or
 *         has methods with different signatures.
 */
static Object create(Context cx, Class<?> cl, ScriptableObject object)
```

When I first worked with generic interfaces in both Java and Javascript, it also helped me quite a lot to understand what is going on, by step debugging my invocations on the created Rhino proxies (but you will of course need the Rhino source to do that, and setting it up can be a little cumbersome).

Also note, that the default Rhino implementation used by the [Java Scripting API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html) does not allow to implement multiple Java interfaces or to extend Java classes. From the [Java Scripting Programmer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#jsengine):

> Rhino's JavaAdapter has been overridden. JavaAdapter is the feature by
>   which Java class can be extended by JavaScript and Java interfaces may
>   be implemented by JavaScript. We have replaced Rhino's JavaAdapter
>   with our own implementation of JavaAdapter. In our implementation,
>   only single Java interface may be implemented by a JavaScript object.

So if you need these features, you will need to install the original Rhino implementation anyway (which makes it easier to set up the source code).

Comment: Thanks. I'm using non-JDK (original) Rhino. Do I understand correctly that due to the fact that Javascript has a dynamic type system, I would only get a type error at the first invocation (if I, for example, tried to pass a `HashMap` to the interface implementation) and not when I actually pass the interface to some library function that might be storing it for some duration of runtime?

Comment: @hexafraction You wouldn't get any type error at all, if you are passing a wrong type to the interface. You would get an error in Javascript, if you try to access a function (representing a Java method), that does not exist while invoking the interface,. But actually the same is also true, if you implement the interface in Java, and ignore the generics. You would then only get a type error, if you actually cast the argument into a wrong type - generic types are erased at runtime. So you can think of the Javascript interface as a simple Java interface, that ignores the generic typing.

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thank you very much. I think I can find an application-level workaround (and frankly, dynamic typing lets implementors be more flexible in this case)